# Why is the result of await/async undefined?

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

I have a route like:

```
router.get("/my_resource", myController.getResult);
```

Then my controller is like:

```
getResult: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const param = req.query.param;
      let response = {};
      if (param) {
        let [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([myModel.getResult1(param), myModel.getResult2(param)]);
        console.log(result1);
        console.log(result2);
      }
      res.send(response);
    } catch (e) { 
        next(e);
    }
  }
```

And my model (which is querying a mongodb) looks like:

```
getResult1: (param) => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoSchema1.findById(param, (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result ? result : {});
      }).select("field1 field2");
    })
  }

getResult2: (param) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoSchema2.findById(param, (error, result) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(result ? result : {});
    }).select("field1 field2");
  })
}
```

Here, when I try to `console.log()` in the model functions I can see that the result is not `undefined`. I get the correct result. However, I can see that the `console.log()` in the controller method gets executed before the `console.log()` in the model methods.

In the code above, I'm making the async calls in parallel with `Promise.all()`. However, even if I try to run one at a time, I still get my result to be undefined in the controller method. What am I doing wrong? Do I need import any module before I can `await`? Thanks.

Comment: Where do `originalMail` and `scrapeResult` come from? You only declare `result1` and `result2` but never use them. Also your `response` is always the empty object.

Comment: @Bergi, sorry t was supposed to be `result1` and `result2`. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your methods `getResult1` and `getResult2` do not return `Promises` objects.

Replace

```
  getResult1: (param) => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoSchema1.findById(param, (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        resolve(result ? result : {});
      }).select("field1 field2");
    })
  }
```

By

```
  getResult1: (param) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoSchema1.findById(param, (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result ? result : {});
      }).select("field1 field2");
    });
  }
```

Or

```
  getResult1: param => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoSchema1.findById(param, (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);

        resolve(result ? result : {});
      }).select("field1 field2"));
  }
```

Or

```
getResult1: async param => (await MongoSchema1.findById(param).select('field1 field2')) || {};
```

Or

```
getResult1: async param => (await MongoSchema1.findById(param, 'field1 field2')) || {};
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I will accept the answer in a few minutes as there a lock here.